# Display code reviews that need to be completed on TFS board

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template, tfs-code-review

Is there any way to do this? I have looked into TFPT, Review Assistant, and the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client` NuGet packages. I just want something that I can create code reviews with which will display the progress of those code reviews on my team's TFS board.

Answer (score 4):

No this currently cannot be done as far as I can tell, at least not without serious mucking around wit the workitem template for Code Review Request.

You may be able to achieve your goal by adding all required fields for tasks to the Code Review Request work item and adding Code Review Request to the TaskCategory, but since this work item type is tightly coupled with the UI implementation I do not know how far you could go before the UI will break.

The [process is largely the same as the work required to add Bugs to the taskboard. so you could experiment with that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/02/12/add-bugs-to-the-task-board-or-backlog-pages/). I suspect you may run into issues around mapping the states of the Code Review to the States of the Task workitem, which will likely break the Visual Studio UI as well.

As an alternative you could create a custom dashboard widget using a Work Item Query. It would show up on your Team's homepage on TFS and would show you your status.